# Three js, replace basic line with thick tapered glowing line

Tags: three.js

I have a simple line that I would like to change:

1. I'd like to make the line thicker, but the linwidth parameter does not work.
2. I'd like the line to taper in one end and glow. Something like the image in the example.

[image]

Below is my current code, does anyone know a simple way to do this?

```
    const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(
        {
            linewidth: 5, color: 'blue', opacity: 1.0, transparent: true
        }
    );
    
    let linepoints = [];
    coordinates.forEach( data => {
        linepoints.push( new THREE.Vector3( data.x, data.y, data.z ) );
    } );
    
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( linepoints );
    
    var curvedline = new THREE.Line( geometry, lineMaterial );
```